# Wrap flex children to the top and side?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given following design Idea from a mobile first standpoint:

Mobile (all 100%):

```
|---------|
| Child 1 |
|---------|

|---------|
| Child 2 |
|---------|

|---------|
| Child 3 |
|---------|

|---------|
| Child 4 |
|---------|

|---------|
| Child 5 |
|---------|
```

I want to achieve the following on desktop (70/30):

```
|-------------| |---------|
|   Child 1   | | Child 3 |
|-------------| |---------|

|-------------| |---------|
|   Child 2   | | Child 5 |
|-------------| |---------|

|-------------| 
|   Child 4   |
|-------------|
```

My first idea was ...

- to set the `flex-base` of 1, 2 and 4 to 70%
- set the `flex-base` of 3 and 5 to 30%
- use `order` to re-align 3 and 5 to the "end"

I thought that flex children tried to wrap around and start at the right top, but they do not.

It will look like this:

```
|-------------|
|   Child 1   |
|-------------|

|-------------|
|   Child 2   |
|-------------|

|-------------| |---------|
|   Child 4   | | Child 3 |
|-------------| |---------| 

|---------|
| Child 5 |
|---------|
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should take a look to `order` css property here you can see an example of blocks ordering https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property

Comment: Hey @ustmaestro, I'm already using `order`... The Flex Children will not reflow to the upper right as I tried to.. they will align up from the point, where the last Element of the previous order ended e.g. Child 4. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since the order of the children is a non-continuous one, I would suggest moving away from flexbox, and instead, use CSS grids if possible (not supported in IE11 for example). There you got the option to position each child as you wish. This would look something like this

```
.container {
  grid-template-columns:  ${isMobile ? 1 : 2};
}

.child-1 {
  grid-column-start: ${isMobile ? auto : 2};
  grid-column-end: auto;
}
```

And then use the `grid-row-start` and end prop to change positions of 3 and 4.

I'm tbh a bit rusty on the grids, but I solved a similar problem with grid a while back. Feel free to dive deeper into grids [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Hey Viktor, thanks for your super fast answer! Unfortunately, I am not able to use Grid on this one, as I need to support IE11. Will add that requirement to the Question now. But I'll take a look at a solution via Grid anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If we can not use Grid, I would go WET on this code and create one version for mobile, one for desktop. Mobile will be simple, as you might have solved that already.

For desktop, you just use Flex to create 2 columns with the 30/70 widths you required. Then you stack your content manually in each column.

If heights need to be the same, then let the outer container take up the full width, and use an inner container to get the right 70/30 widths.

```
///////////////////////////
Container (flex if needed)
|-------------| |---------|
|   Child 1   | | Child 3 |
|-------------| |---------| 
///////////////////////////
///////////////////////////
Container (flex if needed)
|-------------| |---------|
|   Child 5   | | Child 2 |
|-------------| |---------| 
///////////////////////////
```